# Where to put and how to access static, constant data?

Tags: assembly, avr, static-linking, object-files, memory-layout

I have some static, constant data that I need to be able to retrieve at runtime. **Where do I need to put that data and how can I access it?**

I've tried putting the data in `.text` and in `.data`, and using `ld r24, X`. I've also tried using GDB's `print` command. However, with all of these approaches, I am always seeing a 0 result.

**Try 1: `.data`:**

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         00000010  00800100  000000d2  00000146  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  1 .text         000000d2  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .stab         000006cc  00000000  00000000  00000158  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  3 .stabstr      00000054  00000000  00000000  00000824  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
Contents of section .data:
 800100 01010101 01000000 00000000 00000100  ................

Disassembly of section .text:
...
  c2:   a0 50           subi    r26, 0x00       ; 0
  c4:   bf 4f           sbci    r27, 0xFF       ; 255
  c6:   8c 91           ld      r24, X
```

At runtime, this gives me

```
=> 0x000000c6 <_ZN8external6decode17hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3E+18>: 8c 91   ld  r24, X
(gdb) i r r26 r27
r26            0x3  3
r27            0x1  1
(gdb) ni
0x000000c8 in external::decode::hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3 ()
=> 0x000000c8 <_ZN8external6decode17hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3E+20>: 08 95   ret
(gdb) i r r24
r24            0x0  0
(gdb) p *0x103
$8 = 0
(gdb) p *0x800103
$9 = 0
```

**Try 2: `.text`:**

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         00000000  00800100  000000e1  00000155  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  1 .text         000000e1  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .stab         000006cc  00000000  00000000  00000158  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  3 .stabstr      00000054  00000000  00000000  00000824  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING

Disassembly of section .text:
...
  c2:   ae 52           subi    r26, 0x2E       ; 46
  c4:   bf 4f           sbci    r27, 0xFF       ; 255
  c6:   8c 91           ld      r24, X
...
000000d2 <_etext>:
  d2:   01 01           movw    r0, r2
  d4:   01 01           movw    r0, r2
  d6:   01 00           .word   0x0001  ; ????
        ...
  e0:   01 00           Address 0x00000000000000e0 is out of bounds.
.word   0xffff  ; ????
```

and then at runtime:

```
0x000000c6 in external::decode::hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3 ()
=> 0x000000c6 <_ZN8external6decode17hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3E+18>: 8c 91   ld  r24, X
(gdb) i r r26 r27
r26            0xd5 213
r27            0x0  0
(gdb) ni
0x000000c8 in external::decode::hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3 ()
=> 0x000000c8 <_ZN8external6decode17hbbb21fc0c1cdbaf3E+20>: 08 95   ret
(gdb) i r r24
r24            0x0  0
(gdb) p *0xd5
$1 = 0
(gdb) p *0x8000d5
$2 = 0
```

Comment: The section you place the data in shouldn't make a difference. Try to compile a similar program with the C compiler and observe how it accesses such data.

Comment: @fuz: I've added a self-answer; using `lpm`, I was able to get this working, but only with approach #2. Can you expand on why the choice of section shouldn't matter?

Comment: It seems that AVR has separate address spaces for code and data. Does your program include the usual stub to copy the data section to RAM?

Comment: @fuz no it doesn't include that stub. In fact, I want to avoid using up RAM for this, since it's constant data.

Comment: Then you should not put the data into the data section put rather the text or rodata section. But apparently that means that it is in a different address space.

Comment: Right, but for some reason my linker defaulted to putting `.rodata` into `.data` in the final ELF. Hence my question.

Comment: This could be because in C, you can take addresses of everything, do even constants have to reside in RAM. In this case, use the text segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by putting the static data in `.text` (i.e. this is "approach 2" from my original question), and using [`lpm`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_lpm.html) instead of [`ld`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LD.html) to load it.